# How can I change the timezone in strtotime?

Tags: php

Just to sum up here is my code:

```
echo @date('h:i A e', @strtotime($db_order_data['DeliveryDate'])); ?> on <?= @date('d M Y', @strtotime($db_order_data['DeliveryDate']));
```

How can I change the timezone of the specific deliverydate?

Note: I tried to add `define('TIMEZONE', 'Pacific/Taipei');` on the topmost php but still did not work. Any help woud be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: The time itself is the one that I need to change. Including the timezone. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Did you take a look at the docs for strtotime? They mention [date_default_time_zone_set](https://www.php.net/date_default_timezone_set) quite specifically.

Comment: I modified this code into echo @date('h:i A e', @strtotime($db_order_data['DeliveryDate'],new DateTimeZone("Asia/Taipei") )); ?> on <?= @date('d M Y', @strtotime($db_order_data['DeliveryDate']));

the code seems to work but not correctly. The time just becume 6:00pm even using other timezones

Comment: @ccKep It doesn't work. It only changes the timezone of e but not the time itself.

Comment: What is the timezone of the value in `$db_order_data['DeliveryDate']`?

Comment: All those `@`s are going to hide any warnings or errors that might occur in any of these function calls.

Comment: Just use DateTime and the DateTimeZone it takes in the constructor. With that there is virtually no reason to use the functional strtotime. Better yet, use Carbon if you have the option: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: @Nick it is America/Chicago by its default. Without modifications

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime()` will assume the PHP default timezone (set via php.ini or `date_default_timezone_set()`) unless your date string contains a timezone.

Fiddling with global settings at runtime for this is not really best practice. You might be better off using the DateTime classes for this.

```
$dt = new \DateTime($db_order_data['DeliveryDate'], new \DateTimeZone('Pacific/Taipei'));
echo $dt->format('h:i A e') . " on " . $dt->format('d M Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this work, you can use [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects, first creating the object with the timezone of your database values (if it's MySQL, they will probably be UTC), and then adjusting the timezone of the result.

```
$date = new DateTime($db_order_data['DeliveryDate'], new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Taipei'));
echo $date->format('h:i A e') . " on " . $date->format('d M Y');
```

Note that `Pacific/Taipei` is not valid for PHP, you need to use `Asia/Taipei`.

For example, if `$db_order_data['DeliveryDate'] = '2019-04-29 14:30:00';`, the output would be:

```
03:30 AM Asia/Taipei on 30 Apr 2019
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/2umNu)

Comment: timezone is only changing but not the time itself

Comment: @MarkAngeloL.Sison the time changes ok in my demo... What is in the value of `$db_order_data['DeliveryDate']`?

Comment: the original value is 02:53pm but when I apply that code. the time automatically becomes 6:00am w/c is wrong

Comment: @MarkAngeloL.Sison where are you at with this?